# Which one should I use, past simple or past perfect?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

*In November 2001, he ran onto the pitch to play for Inter Milan against Lecce. The fans cheered; he hadn't played almost two years, since he _______ (damage) his knee... He fell down and didn't get up. He___ (injure) his knee again.*

So the answers are： **had damaged, had injured**. I don't understand. Why can't I just say **damaged, injured**?

Comment: He hadn’t played ***for*** almost two... ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Both 'damaged' and 'injured' are fine. There are a few points to consider:

1) The **past perfect** forms could be used because those events referred to by the **perfect** occurred *prior to* their conjugates, thus serving the form's [function](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect/):

a) He damaged his knee *before* he began his two-year hiatus.

b) He injured his knee *before* he fell down.

2) Though we may use the **past perfect** form to *indicate clearly which order a set of events occurred in*, we need not do so. The audience will generally be able to interpret such ordering by factors beyond the sentence.

3) Sometimes we have good reason for *not* using the past perfect form to indicate ordering. For example, [*the **past simple** may suggest a stronger temporal connection between events*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/past-perfect-simple-or-past-simple).

Looking back at your sentences in question we could well opt for the **simple**. Doing so would show us the *strong connection* between:

a) The damaging of the knee and the consequent hiatus.

b) The injuring of the knee and the consequent fall.

Comment: Thank you very much!